# How to return a Vec<String> from a collection in rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

here I am splitting vec into sub-vectors of equal size 4 and then returning a collection, I want the type returned from the collection to be `Vec<String>`. How can I do so?

`let mut split_operations : Vec<String> = vec[2..].chunks(4).collect::<String>();`

This generates the following error:

a value of type `std::string::String` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&[std::string::String]`

value of type `std::string::String` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&[std::string::String]>`

help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<&[std::string::String]>` is not implemented for `std::string::String`rustc(E0277)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type parameter of `collect()` is what the entire thing should be collected to. So the parameter to `collect` and the actual type are redundant, only one is needed.

However Rust doesn't want to guess how or what to the `chunks` are supposed to change: here you have an iterator of *slices* (`Iterator<Item=&[String]`). You can collect an `Iterator<Item=String>` to a `Vec<String>` or to a single `String` (it'll join all the items), but the intermediate slice means Rust's got no idea what's supposed to happen.

If you want each chunk to become a single string, you need to do that explicitely in a `map` e.g.

```rust
    let mut split_operations : Vec<String> = vec[2..].chunks(4)
        .map(|c| c.concat())
        .collect();
```

If you want to play (and / or infuriate your colleagues), you can also write the map callback as `<[_]>::concat`.